# Deleting a provisioning script by id using RETS API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Now that I can add a provisioning script using RETS API. I am trying to delete the provisioning script by id.

I have tried to put the provsioning script id in the URL like:  `https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Provisioning_Hook/deleteObject/64083

I have tried putting id in parameters like:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Provisioning_Hook/deleteObject
{
 "parameters" : [
    {
       "id" : "64083",
    }
 ]
```

}

I have tried removing the id and specify:

```
{
     "parameters" : [
        {
           "64083",
        }
     ]
  }
```

I get returned RC 404, content is {"error":"Service does not exist","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to send the id (Provision Script to delete) as parameter. this should be sent it in the request
Try the following Rest request:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Provisioning_Hook/64083/deleteObject

Method: Get
```

**References:**

- [Rest](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/REST)
- [SoftLayer_Provisioning_Hook::deleteObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Provisioning_Hook/deleteObject)